# SFTP to ZIP File automation to ServiceNow

Tags: automation, zip, sftp

I have a python script that pulls some log files from a server and then uploads them to a windows 2008 R2 SFTP Server.

This script runs when an alarm is triggered by our monitoring platform (EM7).

I need to be able to automatically zip the log files at the time that they're uploaded to the server.

Once they're uploaded to the server and zipped up, I need to automatically attach them to a ServiceNow ticket that is created at the time of the original alarm.

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attachment API in ServiceNow platform to accomplish this task assuming you have the ticket info created by the alarm. You can zip the files loaded to server and stream them to the API and save as an attachment on the ticket created.

For details, please refer to https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound-rest/reference/r_AttachmentAPI-POST.html